# How to enable Gzip compression on CentOS 7 server running remi-php74 on Apache?

Tags: php, apache, gzip, centos7

So far I have done the following based on what I've found;

```
yum -y install lzip oniguruma oniguruma-devel
yum install pcre-devel gcc zlib zlib-devel  libzip-devel make
yum -y install php74-php-pecl-zip.x86_64
echo "extension=/opt/remi/php74/root/usr/lib64/php/modules/zip.so" >> /etc/php.d/zip.ini
systemctl restart httpd
```

Contents of my .htaccess file -

```
<IfModule mod_deflate.c>
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/x-icon
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-truetype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-font-opentype
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/vnd.ms-fontobject
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/ttf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/otf
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE font/opentype
# For Olders Browsers Which Can't Handle Compression
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html
</IfModule>
```

What am I missing or need to do?

According to testing on https://www.giftofspeed.com/gzip-test/ GZip compression is still not working.

Comment: No relation between zip extension and apache gzip output...

Comment: If you use php (from "remi-php74") you need php-pecl-zip, NOT php74-php-pecl-zip... see https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/  and you also don't need and the "devel" stuff you add...